# Como modificar la secuencia de la ejecucion?

Tags: mysql, sql, express

Ocurre algo raro, muy raro, la secuencia no termina completamente, porque? este es mi codigo.

Primero la conexion a la bd.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cnxMysql = function () {

    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '123',
        database: 'key'
    });
}

exports.cnxMysql = cnxMysql;
```

El siguiente codigo estoy tratando de realizar la consulta.

```
let objBD = require('../model/cnxMysql').cnxMysql();

for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
   for(let x=0; x<Object.entries(parameters[i]).length; x++){
   let post;

   post = {ID_INTENTO: result, TIPO: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][0], VALOR: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][1]};
   console.log('111111111111', post);


   objBD.query('INSERT INTO  PARAMETROS SET ?', post, function (err, rows) {
   console.log('22222222222');

           });
           }
    }
```

primero se ejecuta el primer console, pero no entra al segundo, esta es el orden de ejecucion.

```
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.9 }
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'lr', VALOR: 0.1 }
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.5 }
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'lr', VALOR: 0.1 }
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.1 }
22222222222 
22222222222 
22222222222 
22222222222 
22222222222
```

La secuencia  ideal seria:

```
111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.9 }
22222222222 
    111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'lr', VALOR: 0.1 }
22222222222 
    111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.5 }
22222222222 
    111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'lr', VALOR: 0.1 }
22222222222 
    111111111111 { ID_INTENTO: 197, TIPO: 'error', VALOR: 0.1 }
22222222222
```

Tambien modifique mi codigo con async await

```
for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
       for(let x=0; x<Object.entries(parameters[i]).length; x++){
       let post;

       post = {ID_INTENTO: result, TIPO: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][0], VALOR: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][1]};
       console.log('111111111111', post);


           await  setParameters(post);
               }
        }

async function setParameters(post) {
    objBD.query('INSERT INTO  PARAMETROS SET ?', post, function (err, rows) {
        console.log('22222222222', rows);
    });
}
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: no entiendo que es lo raro.. por lo menos, a simple vista, suena logico lo que hace.. pero a simple vista y sin ver los back de que hace cada una de esas funciones...

Comment: @gbianchi lo raro es que por que no se muestra el segundo log seguidamente del primero?

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa no entendi muy bien tu comentario, a que funciones te refieres?

Comment: que es objBD.query? tarda en ejecutarse? ejecuta el console log despues de terminar correctamente?

Comment: @gbianchi edite mi pregunta para mostrar que es objBD, creo que tarda en ejecutarse pero no encuentro la razon, o sera porque estoy insertando muchos datos del arreglo?, A veces se ejecuta bien, inserta bien a la bd, pero a veces no inserta a la bd, y eso es mas raro aun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rw,

El problema que estas teniendo es por la asincrónica de JavaScript.

Esta bien que hayas utilizado 'async/await' para controlar la sincronía pero lo estas utilizando incorrectamente, la forma correcta seria:

Donde creas la conexión necesitas que sea sincronía para que la conexión este creada y lista para usarla:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cnxMysql = async function () {
    return await mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '123',
        database: 'key'
    });
}
exports.cnxMysql = cnxMysql;
```

Donde la utilizas para que se espere a cada consulta que realizas:

```
for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < Object.entries(parameters[i]).length; x++) {
        let post = { ID_INTENTO: result, TIPO: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][0], VALOR: Object.entries(parameters[i])[x][1] };
        console.log('111111111111', post);
        setParameters(post);
    }
}

async function setParameters(post) {
    await objBD.query('INSERT INTO  PARAMETROS SET ?', post, function (err, rows) {
        console.log('22222222222', rows);
    });
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: me sale error objBD.query is not a function   en tiempo de ejecucion

Comment: Según el error, el motivo es porque la varibale 'objDB' esta declarada en un 'scope'  que no puede usar la función 'setParameters'. Podrías enviar el código completo para comprobarlo?